# Dynamics 365: Need help finishing JavaScript event that counts the total "Yes"s in a grid and gives a warning message if the "Yes" count >4

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

In my Dynamics CRM Opportunity form, I've added a Sales Quota Distribution Grid. If more than four Yes's have been entered in the entire grid, I want a warning message (or something similar) to be shown. For example, lets say record "A" t has 4 fields marked "Yes". Record "B" account has zero. If I change one the distributions next to record "B", I want the warning message to appear.

I do not have much experience with coding or JavaScript, but here is what I have come up with so far:

```
function getTotalYesCount(executionContext) {
   var formContext == executionContext.getFormContext();
   var allRows == null;
   var attributeColl == null;
   var idqualifyyescount;
   var sowbomyescount;
   var scopeyescount;
   var closeyescount;
   try {
       //get rows - use the getControl method and pass the grid name.
       var gridContext = formContext.getControl("s_qd"); 
       allRows == gridContext.getGrid().getRows();
       //loop through rows and get the attribute collection
       allRows.forEach(function (row, rowIndex) {
           //get the attribute Collection
           attributeColl == row.data.entity.attributes;
               switch (att.getName()) {
                   case "new_idqualify":
                       if (att.getValue() == "Yes") {
                           idqualifyyescount == idqualifyyescount +1;
                   case "new_sowbom":
                       if (att.getValue() == "Yes") {
                           sowbomyescount == sowbomyescount +1;
                       }
                   case "new_scope":
                       if (att.getValue() == "Yes") {
                           scopeyescount == scopeyescount +1;
                       }
                   case "new_close":
                       if (att.getValue() == "Yes") {
                           closeyescount == closeyescount +1;
                       }
                       }
                       if ((idqualifyyescount + sowbomyescount + scopeyescount +closeyescount) > 4) {                          
                           Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("More than 4 Yes's have been entered in the Sales Quota Distribution.");
                       }                       
}
}
}
}
```

Am I on the right track?  Any help getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Good effort so far. There are a few things I've picked up on that could help you:

1. It's convention in JavaScript for function names to be in camelCase i.e. `getTotalYearsCount` rather than `GetTotalYearsCount`. Your varaibles should also be as such so `closeYesCount`, `scopeYesCount`. [Airbnb's style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript) is a great reference point.
2. JavaScript comparison operator for 'equal to' should be `==` or `===`, not `=`. So you should write `att.getValue() === "Yes"`.
3. It's possible that the values returned from your attribute `getValue()` calls will be boolean rather than strings. So rather than comparing `att.getValue() === "Yes"` you'd compare `att.getValue() === true`. But I can't be sure without knowing your database schema.
4. On your row data object, both `getData()` and `getEntity()` are depracated. You should be able to access the properties directly, so you'd write `row.data.entity.attributes;`.
5. For your requirement it's possible you want to use just `getRows()`. The `getSelectedRows()` you're using will only return the collection of rows that have been selected in the grid, whereas `getRows()` will return all rows. [Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/grids/grid/getrows).
6. You're not actually iterating through your attribute collection `attributeColl`. One way you could, would be to use `filter`:

```js
var idQualify = attributeColl.filter(att => {
    return att.getName === "new_idqualify";
})[0];
```

Comment: Thanks!  Please see above for my updated code. It is still not running correctly.
I didn't quite understand where I should put the filter you mentioned in item #6, can you please explain?  Does it go under each "Case"?

Comment: Another question I have is where should this event get triggered?  OnLoad of the form or OnSave of the grid?  It looks like OnLoad of the grid is not possible.